# Why I cannot see the output of the program I wrote in C# in VS Code when I run it in the terminal

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I am newbie to C# and I'm doing some easy practices in VS code.

I have an array of colors and a method that returns the corresponding index of the inputted color(Resistor Color exercise).

I want to see the result of the program when I run the program in the terminal, but nothing shows!

For example, when I choose the "brown" as an input for the method, I expect to see the 1 in the terminal.

I appreciate if anyone can check what is wrong with the code I wrote.

```
using System;

public class ResistorColor
{
    private void  Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = ColorCode("brown");
        Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
    }

    public static string[] colors = {"black", "brown", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet", "grey", "white"};
    public static int ColorCode(string color)
    {
       return Array.IndexOf(colors, color);
    }

    public static string[] Colors()
    {
        return colors;
    }

}
```

Comment: in the csproj, what is the output type? is it `Exe` ? or is it perhaps `WinExe`?

Comment: btw, posting images of code is really not a good idea - a) we can't copy/paste it to try to repro things, and b) it is really bad for accessibility; whenever possible, posting code as text is infinitely preferable

Comment: also: is there perhaps another file in the solution, called `Program.cs` usually? the entry-point for C# is usually a **`static`** method called `Main`, but your `Main` method is instance (not `static`). This makes me think that the thing we're looking at is *not the entry-point*, and that there is *another* `Main` method somewhere which is the one you're actually running

Comment: @MarcGravell I don't see any Program.cs file in the toolbar. Also when I add static to my Main method it gives me this error:
ResistorColor.cs(5,26): error CS0017: Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point. [/Users/roxana/Exercism/csharp/resistor-color/ResistorColor.csproj]

Comment: that is actually conclusive proof that the problem is exactly what I said in my answer below; so ... *somewhere* there is another code file with a `static` method called `Main`. I can't find it from here, for obvious reasons - you'll have to look, but: it is there! a search for "Main" should find it

Comment: The exercises from the @Exercism website come with a starter code file, I searched for Main and surprisingly this is the only Main exist in the whole file! There is also no Program.cs file! :(

Comment: This sounds like a question for them, then. We can't tell what is going on without being able to see the directory.

Comment: why isn't main static?

Comment: @ShahryarSaljoughi When I add static to the Main method it gives me this error: error CS0017: Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point. 
Although there is no other main in the file!

Comment: @Roksana I guess that's because you are refenrecing `XUnit` . remove the dependency to that test library, and you will be okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are working on a project downloaded from [exercism.io](https://exercism.io).
Those projects are *Test Projects*. meaning that they are not supposed to define any `Main` method. Test projects already internally have some sort of `Main` method!
Anyway, if you want to convert that project into a console project which you can run, you should :

#### 1. remove the references to the test libraries.

Currently your `.csproj` file contains lines like this:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
<PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.1" />
```

Remove these 3 lines. These are adding a dependency to your project and actually converting it into a test project.

#### 2. Define output type of your project:

Make sure that in the '.csproj' file, output type of the project is specified. You should use `Exe` for `OutputType`

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
   <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

#### 3- Use a valid signature for `Main` method:

There exists a few valid signatures for `Main` and in all of them, it should be `static`

#### 4- You're done!

now you can run : `dotnet run` and see the output.

#### Update:

You may have a different version of .net core sdk installed. So do not copy its value from snippets I've wrote, stick to the version you already have. These snippets are just for explaining.

Answer (score 2):

It looks likely that you have two `Main` methods; the **instance** `Main` method you've shown in the question, and a `static` method called `Main` *somewhere else*.

A quick way to test this is to simply rename your `Main` method to something else (`Main2` perhaps; naming is hard!); if the code still compiles, *it was never the entry point*.

---

To be the "entry point" (i.e. the thing that runs when you run your exe), a method needs to be `static` (and be called `Main`, and have a suitable signature such as `void Main(string[])`, although many other signatures are allowed), so the code shown in the question is *just a method that happens to be called `Main`*. The actual code that runs when you run your exe is probably in a different file, typically `Program.cs` - and it is probably empty.

Answer (score 0):

Youu need to also add `ReadLine` in order to see the output:

```
...
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: in virtually every scenario I can think of: no, you really don't; `Console.WriteLine` by itself works just fine; there *are* some curious timing problems if you are consuming input keys/bytes one by one, but... that isn't the case here

Comment: @MarcGravell I think the point here is to pause the application after writing to the console, so the console doesn't close itself right away. Using `Console.ReadLine();` is a basic way to do this

Comment: @Rafalon if you run things from a terminal, as appears to be the case here (see the `dotnet run` etc), the **same terminal** is typically used for the output, so: that becomes a non-issue

Answer (score 0):

You can also add Console.Readkey(); at the end of your project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: And what would this do to solve this problem?